# Cant run app in React native on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, glog

I'm making React native iOS app on MacBook Air m1. When I run `npx react-native run-ios` in vscode I got a lot of errors:

[image]

When I try to build it from Xcode (from 'name.xcworkplace')  I got these errors:

[image]

When I build it from Xcode (from 'name.xcodeproj'), it runs the metro server, but the build on iOS simulator fail. And I get these errors:

[image]

Here is my Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'authier' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )


  target 'authierTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  #use_flipper!()

  #post_install do |installer|
   # react_native_post_install(installer)
  #end
end
```

I'm trying to figure it out for one week and I'm pretty much lost.
If you have any question feel free to ask!!
Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Did you try creating a new project & running it? Try to run a project that is running latest version of RN

Comment: Okay I will try!!

Comment: hello @PetrŠpác did your issue resolved, I am using MacBook Air M1 , I didn't face any issue

Comment: I created new project and it showed same issues

Comment: Try to run `npx react-native doctor` and resolve all the issues mentioned after the cmd completes if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Xcode version. I use version 13 beta. After I reinstalled the Xcode and downloaded the stable 12.5 version it works.